# LINQ OrderBy query

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by

I have the following that pulls through a list of suppliers:

```
public List<tblSupplierPerformance> GetSupplierInfo(string memberid, string locationid, string supplieridname)
{
    MyEntities suppliers = new MyEntities();

    var r = (from p in suppliers.tblSupplierPerformances
             where p.MemberId == memberid && p.LocationId == locationid
             orderby p.TotalPurchaseQuantity 
             select p)
            .Distinct();

    if (supplieridname != "0")
        r = r.Where(p => p.SupplierIDName == supplieridname);

    return r.ToList();
}
```

However, when this runs, the orderby doesn't seem to be ordering.

I think, *think*,  I need to implement the orderby at the "return r." stage,  but I don't really know how to do this or I could be very much wrong all over the shop!

Any pointers gladly received.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I *suspect* it's the `Distinct` call which is messing up the ordering... although as you're not joining or doing anything like that, I'm not sure why you need distinct - isn't each entity naturally distinct?

Anyway, you could certainly move the ordering to the return statement:

```
return r.OrderBy(p => p.TotalPurchaseQuantity).ToList();
```

Comment: Just for anyone who is looking for something simialr, I did the above but with OrderByDescending which, funnily enough, ordered the totalpurchaseQuantity descending.

Thanks Jon.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to implement order by in the return

```
return r.ToList().OrderBy(o => o.Column1);
```

Comment: That will perform the sorting in .NET itself rather than at the database, which is likely to be less efficient. Putting it *before* the call to `ToList` does it in SQL.

Comment: @Skeet: you are referring to **LINQ to SQL** or **LINQ to Entities** right?  It doesn't matter with **LINQ to Objects** though right?